# tampermonkey doesn't load the script first time

Tags: tampermonkey

when I access any page from the main navigation of the website, tampermonkey doesn't load the script, so I have to refresh the page. any idea how to fix this ?

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         product-view
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://mywebsite.com/
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=mywebsite.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function(){

productView();

// Product View
function productView()
{
  alert('1');
}
});
```

Comment: This is a modern SPA site. Use navigation.addEventListener("navigate", e => { productView() })

Comment: my website is not SPA, it's just normal website with pages, I don't understand why I should trigger it on navigation click, the method will be triggered normally on refreshing the page, my issue is the first load only when I go from the navigation.

Comment: SPA looks the same as a "normal website with pages".

Comment: You can also use [window.onurlchange](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:window.onurlchange).